# Google Apps Script works in \dev but no in \exec mode

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, permissions, publish

First I have to apologize because English is not my native language and also because I'm just starting in developing. Sorry for all of that.

My question is that when I deploy my app script as a web app the page does not work; but when I used the "Test web app for your latest code" it does work. I don't understand why in the first case (the url finishes with a \exec) appears an error and in the second works nice (the url finishes with a \dev).

The Google Drive error is : *The file cannot be opened at this time. Please check the address and try again.*

I'm so confused because the web app was working nice, and suddenly it started to show that error, but I did not change anything in the code.

I don´t know if it is related with permissions. I've tried to create new versions but it does not solve it.

Any idea how can I solved it?

Comment: First try using your web app in incognito mode, if the problem persist, add a  [mcve] and the publish as web app settings for your web app.

Comment: "Disable webapp" and then "publish it again".

Comment: Can you publish a new version? Does the problem persist?

Comment: OMG thanks Rubén, in incognito mode works! Why does this happen? Do you know how to fix it to work in normal mode?

Comment: @mateocangrejoangel it perhaps happens because you need to clear your browser cache in "normal" mode.

Comment: There might be several reasons... start by the simple solutions like clearing the cache and deleting the cookies, if you need further help, make a [mcve] and update your question.